# bash: double vs single brackets in file test expression evaluation

Tags: bash, shell

I have a question about file test expressions in bash. Here is a simple script to illustrate my question:

```
set -x
read -p "Enter a filename: " var1
if [ - e $var1 ]
then
    echo file exists
else
    echo file not found
fi
```

There are three scenarios:

1. At the prompt, I enter  `foo` , which is a file that exists in the directory from which I'm running the script. As expected, the output is  `file exists` .
2. At the prompt, I enter  `bar` . No such file exists in the directory from which I'm running the script. As expected, the output is  `file not found` .
3. At the prompt, I hit  `<enter>`  without typing anything. Surprisingly, the output is  `file exists` .

If I use  `if [[ -e $var1 ]]` , i.e., double brackets instead of single, the behavior is correct: even in the third case, I get `file not found`.

I stuck a  `set -x`  at the top of the file to see what was going on. With single brackets, the variable is evaluated as:  `'[' -e ']'` . With double, it is evaluated as  `[[ -e '' ]]` . This is interesting. Why is the expression being evaluated differently in the two cases?

I would be grateful for an explanation. Sorry if I'm missing the obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's how they work. `[[` is smarter than `test`, and should be used except where strict compatibility with `sh` is required.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio. Based on your reply I did some more searching and found this link: [link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) that explained a lot.

Comment: greycat's site is awesome. Required reading for the serious bash script writer.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the claim that [[ should be used in favor of test, and would re-phrase it as: '[[ should only be used when you are absolutely certain that your script will never need to be run under a minimal shell.'

Answer (score 6):

change to `if [ -e "$var1" ]`

You can find more details of `[]` and `[[ ]]` [Here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html)